# Image conversion - can't access the element from struct inside another

Tags: c, image-processing, struct

I'm writing a program to manipulate images .PPM based on a template given by my professor. The template has these structures:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned char gray;
} PPMGrayPixel;

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
    PPMGrayPixel *data;
} PPMGrayImage;
```

I'm trying to convert a regular .ppm to a gray scale .ppm. Actually, in this case, I already have an empty grayscale image with the same size that my original image. This grayscale file just have one channel of color (the original has three). I'm okay with the formula to convert, but I think I'm missing something while I try to access the elements of the grayscale file.

I'm not worried to set the right number, I just want to set the values for black and white now. I want to be sure that I'm accessing the right pixel.

This is my code:

```
PPMGrayImage * ConvertToGrayFromColorImage(PPMImage *img) {

PPMGrayImage *img2;
img2 = CreateEmptyGrayImageFromColorImage(img);


for (int i=0; i < img2->x*img2->y; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        img2.data[i].gray = 0;
    }
    else {
        // sign 1
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in the logic of the problem or in sintax?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error?  Most likely trying to access the members of `img2` with the `.` operator.

Comment: You have img2->x, img2->y, but then you have img2.data.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` — what does the compiler report?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? img2->data[i].gray = img->data[i*3].red;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img2.data[i].gray = 0;
```

`img2` is a **pointer** to struct, so you cannot access its members directly. You have to write:

```
(*img2).data[i].gray = 0;
```

or:

```
img2->data[i].gray = 0;
```

Comment: This is true, but the nature of the OP's problem is very unclear.